# Setting up ASP.NET Identity multi factor

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm setting up a REST API project using ASP.NET Core Identity for user management only (so this will be my identity provider). What I would like to also add is multi factor authentication (I would prefer Microsoft's authenticator). I don't know how to do that exactly and I could not find anything on the web which I could use.

Did anyone had to implement this and if so willing to share a repo , code sample or something ?

My app consists from an asp.net core backend and a react app.

Comment: Are these things the Microsoft Authenticator you need? https://www.govteams.gov.au/set-multi-factor-authentication